Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is very slow even without running any app
I’m experiencing performance issues with my PC, recently after installing latest version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS), which has become noticeably slow over time. Simple tasks, like opening files, launching applications, and browsing, are taking significantly longer than expected, which is affecting my overall productivity. I’ve attempted some basic troubleshooting steps, such as restarting the computer, running disk cleanup, and ensuring there are no unnecessary programs running in the background. However, these actions haven’t resolved the issue.
I am using 500 GB HDD toshiba, intel Core i3, Dell.
